# MySQL want all results from left table and filter only the right table with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Let us assume i have ticket's table:

*ticket's table:*

t_id,  comment

*ticket_detail's table:*
t_detail_id,  t_id,  note,  tech_viewed

I want to do like this,

```
select
                T.t_id as 'TicektID',
                TK.tk_category as 'Category',
                ifnull(T.contact_person,'N/A') as 'Contact_Person',
                T.comment as 'Employee Comment',
                COUNT(TD.t_detail_id) as 'User Comment',
                T.t_status
                from sun_it_tickets T
                LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT * from sun_it_ticket_categories
                )TK ON TK.tk_id = T.tk_id
                LEFT JOIN sun_it_tickets_detail TD ON TD.t_id = T.t_id
                where TD.tech_viewed = 0
                ORDER BY T.submit_time
```

other table also left joined (ignore it).

What i want it i want the count of rows from the 'sun_it_tickets_detail' table where tech_viewed = 0.

This will only return the rows matched only tech_viewed = 0, but i want other results also "COUNT(TD.t_detail_id) as 'User Comment'," like this will give count 0, if nothing matches.

Comment: It's not clear what you want as results.  Do you want ticket IDs that have UserComments not yet reviewed by a Tech?  Do you want the counts in the results, or just ticket_id, and user comments?  From your description it sounds like you're mixing summary and detail information in one query results.

Comment: This is what i want "Do you want ticket IDs that have UserComments not yet reviewed by a Tech?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the condition to the `on` clause.

```
select T.t_id as TicektID, TK.tk_category as Category,
       coalesce(T.contact_person, 'N/A') as Contact_Person,
       T.comment as Employee_Comment,
       COUNT(TD.t_detail_id) as num_comments, 
       T.t_status
from sun_it_tickets T left join
     sun_it_ticket_categories tk
     on TK.tk_id = T.tk_id left join
     sun_it_tickets_detail TD 
     on TD.t_id = T.t_id and TD.tech_viewed = 0
group by Category, Contact_Person, Employee_Comment, t_status
order by max(T.submit_time);
```

Notes:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- All non-aggregated columns should be in the `group by`.
- I suspect you are selecting too many columns, but your question is not clear on what results you want.
- The `order by` should be on a `group by` column or an aggregation expression.
- `coalesce()` is an ISO/ANSI standard function, so I prefer using it to database-specific alternatives.